# How to make item highlight border span the complete TreeView width (TreeViewItem selection behavior like VS Solution Explorer)?

Tags: wpf, treeviewitem

There is a margin on the left of the TreeViewItem when selected in Default TreeView style:

[image]

So i want to edit the style of TreeViewItem to make it looks like VS Solution style:

[image]

I know the default ControlTemplate of TreeViewItem is:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"/>
    <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Grid.Column="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
    </Border>
    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

and the left margin is from `Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"`

So how can I make it look like VS Solution style(keep the indent and Not to leave space of background color at the beginning )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very quick and simple solution would require to add a custom highlight border and give it a negative `Margin`.

The following example dynamically calculates the negative left margin by listening to the `Selected` routed event. To make it work the highlight `Border` must span all columns and have the name `"HighlightBorder"` assigned. The hosting `Grid` must be named `"RootGrid"`. We need to access the root grid to get the actual indention.

**`TreeViewItem` style:**
Note that the Style is missing essential triggers to handle visibility of the `ToggleButton` and the `ItemsPresenter`.

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
  <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="AdjustHighlightBorder_OnSelectedItemChanged" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Border>
          <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="HighlightBorder" 
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                    Background="DodgerBlue" 
                    Visibility="Hidden" />

            <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" ClickMode="Press" Content="+"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
            <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Grid.Column="1"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
              <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Border>
            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
          </Grid>

        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="HighlightBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Handler for the `Selected` routed event:**
Determine the level of the currently selected node to calculate the actual indention of the highlight border.

```
private void AdjustHighlightBorder_OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
  if (!(routedEventArgs.Source is TreeViewItem treeViewItemContainer 
        && treeViewItemContainer.IsSelected))
  {
    return;
  }

  var highlightBorder = treeViewItemContainer.Template.FindName("HighlightBorder", treeViewItemContainer) as Border;
  var rootGrid = treeViewItemContainer.Template.FindName("RootGrid", treeViewItemContainer) as Grid;
  double indention = rootGrid.ColumnDefinitions.First().ActualWidth;

  // Determine the level of currently selected node
  int treeLevel = 0;
  DependencyObject parent = treeViewItemContainer;
  do
  {
    parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
    switch (parent)
    {
      case TreeViewItem _:
        treeLevel++;
        break;
      case TreeView _:

        // Root node reached --> apply indention
        Thickness highlightBorderMargin = highlightBorder.Margin;
        highlightBorderMargin.Left = treeLevel * -indention;
        highlightBorder.Margin = highlightBorderMargin;
        return;
    }

  } while (parent != null);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this method before, and it is a simple and quick solution. If there is no better way (such as using only xaml code), I will change it to a `ValueConverter` and apply it in my app.

Comment: You have to use C# to calculate the exact indention of the current item. If you are not interested to make it clean, you can apply a constant negative margin instead. You ´can then use a simple trigger in XAML to set the margin of the HighlightBorder to e.g., `-5000,0,0,0`. If know the tree will stay low, you may do it this way. This is just an example implementation. I personally would either create an attached behavior or even better extend the `TreeView` class.

Comment: If your tree control needs more special features and because the stretched highlight requires specifically and named UI elements, I would prefer to create a custom `TreeViewItem` to encapsulate the logic (which would require to extend `TreeView` too, to override the default item container).